# Не подключается бандл в Symfony

Tags: symfony, консоль

Когда пытаюсь подключать бандл в Symfony, консоль в Windows пишет:

> php is not recognized

Comment: Может, всё-таки `symfony` ;) никогда не использовал cmd, так как в качестве локальной среды использую openserver, который даёт нормальную консоль, через которую можно взаимодействовать с сервером.
____
Да и проблема ваша в том что пути не прописаны для php.exe
____
@Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Решение этой проблемы простое:

Мой компьютер -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Переменные среды -> Path -> Изменить -> Вставляем путь до папки с PHP -> OK -> OK`

Comment: Дополню: машине нужно знать полный путь до исполняемого файла, чтобы его выполнить, например `/usr/bin/php` или `C:\Program Files\Vendor\binary.exe`. Чтобы не писать эту байду каждый раз из консоли, придумали две штуки - относительные пути (относительно текущей рабочей папки) и $PATH - такую переменную, в которую записываются все папки, в которых содержатся исполняемые файлы, к которым нужен быстрый доступ по имени. После того, как нужная папка попала в $PATH, ОС имеет возможность поискать в ней нужный бинарник до того, как вываливаться с ошибкой.